# Wordpress TinyMCE side palette

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

As you can see on an illustration, I looking for right way to place a some kind of palette/side panel/details window near editor.

[image]

I can do it just with an js like: 
a) create space under "mceIframeContainer"; b) change the width of an editor "Iframe", and c) embed extra "div" on a right side:

[image]

But it not looks like "native way". Might be TinyMCE of WP have some kind hooks or "right places", where I have to put a piece of code?

Comment: The area you're highlighting is the *very content* of a `textarea` field. I believe that nothing short of heavy JavaScript trickery will get your desired result.